# Deleting Firebase Database on new design

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Recently Firebase updated their design for the console and I can't find how to delete a Database.

I came across this post: [How do I delete a database from Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373583/how-do-i-delete-a-database-from-firebase)

But they only explain how to delete a project or to empty the database.

**I would like to be able to delete completely the `ferral` database**

[image: databases]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to delete a database from a project. As the linked answer says, deleting the data is the only option.

Comment: Oh I see that's a bit of a shame